# From OSX to Ubuntu: I need help on common shortcuts

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, shortcuts, macosx

I installed ubuntu on my macbookpro... I'm already comfortable with the bash and apt-get tasks, and the OS seems pretty easy to understand and use, however since I'm used to use a lot of shortcuts in OSX, I'm having an hard time trying to figure out how some stuff work in ubuntu.

1. For example on OSX in EACH program is possible to open the preferences/settings panel with CMD+, (yes, the comma key!) it seems that in ubuntu each program has it's own shortcut or is even missing... am I wrong? Can I create a cross-application shortcut like that?
2. Moreover, in order to quit from a program in OSX EACH program can be closed using CMD+q, as far as I'm seeing some app on ubuntu has CTRL+q equivalent, but not all... once again: can I create/is there a cross-app command like that?
3. On the ALT+TAB view in OSX I can use the same shortcut (CMD+q) to close programs... is it possible to close programs from that view in ubuntu?
4. In applications that make use of multiple windows, on OSX I can see each window by pressing F10... what is the equivalent on ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can press and hold 'Super' (like CMD) key and see hints for keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your desktop and hold the super key (In my case it's the windows key), it will show the shortcuts for unity. And you can also create shortcuts by going into system settings -> keyboard -> shortcuts.